# Auto Update with install4j with a subset of the Libraries

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to deliver an update which contains only the updated libraries and not the whole package of data. in our application only a few files are updates regularly. The other ones never. With Auto update over the net this would result in a much smaller package...

Is such a setup possible and how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by saving your project to a different file (keeing the application ID) and removing the unnecessary files from the distribution tree. When you compile that project, an updates.xml file is created as usual. Use that updates.xml file for auto-updates instead of the updates.xml file from the standalone installer project.